# Encryption message in java

Tags: java

i am a project about using java's bouncycastle to do the encryption.

However, when I encrypt the message, it throws an exception for me.

javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: data not block size aligned

I am using Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding, and the message is an xml.

```
public static void main(String args[]){ 
     String message = "<abc>ABCDEFG</abc>"; 
     String key = "key"; 
     byte[] b = encrypt(message.getBytes(), key.getBytes());
}

public byte[] encrypt(byte encrypt[], byte en_key[]) { 
     try { 
           SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(en_key, "Blowfish"); 
           Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding"); 
           cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, en_key); 
           return cipher.doFinal(encrypt); 
     } catch (Exception e) { 
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null; 
         }

}
```

Could anyone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062015/how-to-solve-javax-crypto-illegalblocksizeexception-data-not-block-size-aligned

Comment: public static void main(String args[]){
String message = "<abc>ABCDEFG</abc>";
String key = "key";

byte[] b = encrypt(message.getBytes(), key.getBytes());
}

public byte[] encrypt(byte encrypt[], byte en_key[]) {
    try {           
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(en_key, "Blowfish");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, en_key);  
        return cipher.doFinal(encrypt); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null; 
    }
}

Comment: can you edit your question and put your code there (formatted as code, using the "0101010" icon) instead of putting it in a comment?

Answer (score 6):

You are using `NoPadding` and the size of your input data must not match the block size of the cipher, so an `IllegalBlockSizeException` is being thrown. If you use NoPadding you need to make sure that your input is a multiple of 8 bytes.

Specify a padding scheme. Change to `Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding` and it should work.

**Padding it manually with null bytes:**

Create a new array with a bigger size that is a multiple of 8 and then copy the old array into it.

```
public static byte[] encrypt(byte encrypt[], byte en_key[]) {

    if(encrypt.length % 8 != 0){ //not a multiple of 8
        //create a new array with a size which is a multiple of 8
        byte[] padded = new byte[encrypt.length + 8 - (encrypt.length % 8)];

        //copy the old array into it
        System.arraycopy(encrypt, 0, padded, 0, encrypt.length);
        encrypt = padded;
    }

    try {
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(en_key, "Blowfish");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(encrypt);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it must be used NoPadding...
Because after I used PKCS5Padding, the server has no response.

Comment: Yes, it does. Try printing out the bytes returned by the `encrypt` method.

Comment: Also, If you use NoPadding you need to make sure that your input is a multiple of 8 bytes.

How can I change my input to a multiple of 8 bytes?

Comment: Why do you want to change your input to be a multiple of 8? It's easier to use `PKCS5Padding` which will take care of both encryption and decryption for you.

Comment: Because the project has a server and it is using nopadding to do encrypt & decrypt. 
I need to encrypt the message before send to server.

Comment: Yes, I did it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]){ 
     String message = "<abc>ABCDEFG</abc>"; 
     String key = "key"; 
     byte[] b = encrypt(message.getBytes(), key.getBytes());
}

public byte[] encrypt(byte encrypt[], byte en_key[]) { 
     try { 
           SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(en_key, "Blowfish"); 
           Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding"); 
           cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, en_key); 
           return cipher.doFinal(encrypt); 
     } catch (Exception e) { 
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null; 
     }
}
```