# EncryptionException: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher

Tags: java, cryptography, base64

I have inherited an old java project from 2006 (the original dev is long gone, and I've never coded Java before) where I am getting this error:

> EncryptionException: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher

The code it references looks like this:

```
public String decrypt( String encryptedString ) throws EncryptionException
{
    if ( encryptedString == null || encryptedString.trim().length() <= 0 )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "encrypted string was null or empty" );

    try
    {
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret( keySpec );
        cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key );
        BASE64Decoder base64decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        byte[] cleartext = base64decoder.decodeBuffer( encryptedString );
        byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal( cleartext );

        return bytes2String( ciphertext );
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new EncryptionException( e );
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure of the inner workings of the program, but I do know that in this project directory are a few config files, and a key.properties file. As far as "Input Lengths" go (as the error message refers to), my the password for the database is 15 chars long, and the "key" in key.properties is 25 chars long. I have no idea if that matters or not.

Things to note:

- I have tried changing the DB password to 16 chars (a multiple of 8) but to no avail.
- I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062015/how-to-solve-javax-crypto-illegalblocksizeexception-data-not-block-size-aligned) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183853/encryption-message-in-java) and they have not helped
- I am moving this project from one server to another. It works on its original server.
- The original server runs JRE 1.4.2. The new server runs JRE 1.6u27.
- I **REALLY** don't want to have to rebuild the .jar. I am not a java developer and the project is pretty massive.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I see two possibilities : JRE 1.6 has more strict validation rules reagarding encrypted message length that JRE 1.4.2, or the way strings are transformed to bytes is not the same on both platforms, due for example to a difference regarding their default encoding. More code would be needed to examine the situation further. Anyway, you could decrypt the message where it works, and re-encrypt it on the other platform to generate a new, valid, encrypted message.

Comment: What does that keySpec look like? What's the actual algorithm you're supposed to use?

Answer (score 5):

The input to which the error message refers is the cipher text (oddly-named `cleartext`), the result of the Base-64 decoding operation. Make sure that the `encryptedString` you are passing to this method decodes to a byte array with length that is a multiple of 8.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I have an external config file that to me looked like it was storing the database password in plain text. It turns out, the password in the "dbPassword" tag in my XML was an encoded version of said password. There is a separate process I was supposed to run that encodes the password, stores the key, and puts the encoded version in the config file. Basically, I was not passing in an encrpytedString at all. The string I was passing in was not a multiple of 8, nor a valid Base64 value.

Comment: @erickson- So basically, the length of 2 arrays byte[] cleartext and byte[] ciphertext should be a multiple of 8, is it so? Is that enough to get rid of the exception?

Comment: @Shivam657 In the original post, the names of the clear text and the cipher text appear to be wrong, given as `ciphertext` and `cleartext`, respectively. So that makes your question a bit ambiguous. Also, it depends on the mode and padding specified for the cipher. But for something like AES with CBC and PKCS #7 padding, the cipher text will always be a multiple 16 (the AES block size). For DES or 3DES, the block size is 8, so the cipher text will be a multiple of 8 with the same mode and padding.

Comment: @erickson- Thanks for your comment, now I have a feeling that byte[16] ciphertext should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not change the JRE version unless you want to re-examine the code. I would try downgrading your JRE version on the new server before anything else, especially since the code previously worked.