# Java decryption throws an exception

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, des

Here is my encryption method(value is an input parameter):

```
 byte key_bytes[] = "12345678".getBytes();
 SecretKeySpec _keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key_bytes, "DES");
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"); // Yes, I know I shouldn't use DES
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, _keyspec);

 byte[] utf8 = value.getBytes("UTF8");
 byte[] enc = cipher.doFinal(utf8);   // Encrypt

 String encrypted = new String(new Base64().encode(enc));

 return URLEncoder.encode(encrypted, "UTF-8");
```

Here is my decryption method(value is an input parameter):

```
byte key_bytes[] = "12345678".getBytes();
SecretKeySpec _keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key_bytes, "DES");
Cipher dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, _keyspec);

byte[] dec = new Base64().decode(value);
byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);  // Decrypt, throws exception
return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
```

And I get an Exception:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

I've read different topics, so I figured out, that this exception occurs, when there is no padding and there is another cipher mode. So, what's wrong?

Comment: Where is your `URLDecoder`? And it mainly occurs if your ciphertext is not a multiple of the blocksize (8 for DES) anymore.

Comment: Note that using DES is insecure, ECB is insecure and sending a ciphertext without authentication tag (HMAC) over a network is insecure as well.

Comment: I mentioned that, that DES is unsecure, ECB is unsecure, but requirements are requirements

Comment: @JohnSmith Check again my updated answer and comment.

Comment: @owlstead can you give an example of using HMAC with such type of encryption?

Comment: Well, you use - a preferably different - key for the HMAC calculation, then calculate a HMAC over the ciphertext and - if used - the IV and other configurable encryption parameters that are send. Then you verify the HMAC **before** decryption. That's it really.

Comment: @owlstead thanks for your advice, I'll keep it in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As exception stack says, length must be multiple of 8.

So, length of 8, 16, 24,... are valid for **key bytes**.

Try with length of 8 (12345678)

```
byte key_bytes[] = "12345678".getBytes();
```

If error persists, you can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567996/illegal-block-size-exception-input-length-must-be-multiple-of-16-when-decrypting)

#### Updated

If you want to use `URLDecoder`, try with this code in your decrypt method,

```
String decryptd = URLDecoder.decode(value, "UTF-8");
byte[] dec = new Base64().decode(decryptd);
byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);  
return new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: sorry, I've edited the question, in the source they are 8 charachters long

Comment: @JohnSmith You may need to follow the link in updated answer.

Comment: I don't see any difference, only encryption standard and UTF-8 encoding/decoding, used in my code

Comment: @JohnSmith The problem is in your encrypt method if you return `encrypted` string instead of `return URLEncoder.encode(encrypted, "UTF-8");`, all will be ok.

Comment: yep, it helped, thnx!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an `URLDecoder` in your decryption method. Note that if the string has been compromised in any other way, and the length is not a multiple of the block size anymore that you will receive this exception for both the ECB and CBC modes of operation.

Comment: I use apache's Base64 encoder, URL is decoded above, in another method, so value in input is already decoded

Comment: Works on my system otherwise. Check if the string received is the string send! Note that this is why you should create a SSCCE!

Comment: the string, which I recieve on the output of encryption method equals the string, which is given as input in decryption

Comment: Could you show us an example input string used for decryption that fails with this exception? Preferably edit it into the answer and respond that you did so here.