# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException when using blowfish in java

Tags: java, blowfish

```
String key = "my_own_key_which_should_be_quite_long";
byte[] keyData = key.getBytes();
SecretKeySpec myKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyData, "Blowfish");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey);
String input = "string to encrypt";
try {
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
    System.out.println(new String(encrypted));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: 7 trailing bytes is thrown by the doFinal method. What is the problem?
What's the most interesting - no matter how long the key string is the exception is always the same - 7 trailing bytes.

Comment: Aside from the block size problem, you *really* shouldn't use the platform default encoding to convert the string to a byte array, and you shouldn't try to convert opaque binary data (the encrypted byte array) to a string like that - use base 64.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: data not block size aligned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062015/how-to-solve-javax-crypto-illegalblocksizeexception-data-not-block-size-aligned)

Comment: OMFG, Jon Skeet has commented my question, now my life is filled with meaning

Comment: gentlemen, it's not an exact duplicate

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question seems pretty appropriate: "Furthermore, this is a block cipher, so the input must be a multiple of the block length. With the crypto provider not doing padding, you need to ensure yourself that your input is a multiple of the block size, else encryption/decryption will not be possible and you'll get this error." Did you notice that, and have you tried making sure that the input (not the key, but the value you encrypt) is a multiple of the block size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, using Gnucrypto library has solved this problem